# Either-or condition for set of constraints

Tags: optimization, constraints, binary-programming

Consider the following optimization problem
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\text{min} & \sum_{j\in J} c_jx_j \\
& \quad \sum_{j\in J} a_{1j}x_j \leq b_1 \\
& \quad \sum_{j\in J} a_{2j}x_j \leq b_2 \\
& \quad x_j \geq 0 \quad \forall j\in J
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
It is well known that, if we need to impose that just one of these two constraints must be satisfied, then we can use introduce a binary variable $y\in\{0,1\}$ and two upper bounds $M_1$ and $M_2$ so that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\text{min} & \sum_{j\in J} c_jx_j \\
& \quad \sum_{j\in J} a_{1j}x_j \leq b_1 + M_1y\\
& \quad \sum_{j\in J} a_{2j}x_j \leq b_2 +M_2(1-y)\\
& \quad x_j \geq 0 \quad \forall j\in J
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Now, imagine that we wish that just one of the following sets of constraints
\begin{equation*}
\left\{\sum_{j\in J} a_{ij}x_j \leq b_i, \quad i\in I\right\}, \quad \left\{\sum_{j\in J} a_{kj}x_j \leq b_k, \quad k\in K\right\},
\end{equation*}
with $I\cap K = \emptyset$ is satisfied. How can we formulate the optimization problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your special case of $|I|=|K|=1$ to obtain the following formulation of the general case:
\begin{align}
\sum_{j\in J} a_{ij}x_j &\le b_i + M_i y &&\text{for $i\in I$}\\
\sum_{j\in J} a_{kj}x_j &\le b_k + M_k(1-y) &&\text{for $k\in K$}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That makes sense to me.

Comment: What would happens if we substitute $\leq$ by an "="? How these constraints should be modified?

Comment: To force equality, include also the opposite inequality: $$-\sum_{j\in J} a_{ij}x_j \le -b_i - M_i y$$